# Does careers have a forum?

Tags: feature-request

Does the careers area have a forum like the other areas?  It seems to be the only area that is not forum based.  People who need jobs would benefit from a forum, wouldn't they?

Comment: A SE site is not a forum.

Comment: Typically, career oriented questions aren't a good fit for a Q&A platform. The questions tend to repeat in an infinite loop, with just a few variables changing each time. You could, however create a [chat room](http://stack.stackexchange.com) if one doesn't exist to discuss tips and tricks of tuning your Careers 2.0 profile.

Comment: Ok, thanks, in the future, I will not use the word 'forum' to describe SE.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I think there are legitimate questions that would not result in an infinite loop.  I figure I am going to have one more job before I retire, and I do not want to end up in a bad profession or at a bad company.  I want all the facts I can get, not just what is in the job ad or what some recruiter tells me, in order to make the right decision.

Comment: @David I left a (more specific) answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't have "forums" *anywhere* on Stack Exchange; we have question and answer websites. Maybe this seems like nitpicking to you but the distinction is important to the character of Stack Exchange: We don't have *discussions* as you often see on a forum, we have people asking questions, with several proposed answers.

If you think that the careers area needs a Q&A area, then what problem are you hoping it will solve? You can propose sites on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), though.

Comment: There are many questions that job seekers might have, such as what interviews are like at particular companies, what company culture is like, etc.  When someone is changing their workplace, it is a life altering event, which I would think deserves more attention than a simple job ad.

Comment: @David, I don't think Stack Exchange sites are ideal for that kind of question to be honest (though don't let my doubts stop you trying to gather support for a site over on area 51 if you disagree). The SE sites tend to be based around factual questions based on broad areas of knowledge. Company culture at specific companies seems to be both too subjective and too localised to be a good fit in with the typical SE site culture.

Comment: I really appreciate the reply and I may check out Area 51 later.  I think I will continue to pursue this.  I believe that in this technological world, a company is less of a qualitative manifestation, and more like a component that can be reviewed in a quantitative manner.  And since the recruiters, HR, etc, do not know much, it is up to the job seekers.  Thanks again.

Comment: Believe me David, if you / all of us can make such a site work within the SE format I'll be visiting it myself. We've all had to make that leap to a new job so I think everyone here would agree with you that the sort of info you're talking about is valuable.

Answer (score 5):

Career oriented questions have demonstrated to be an ill fit for our Q&A engine. The questions tend to repeat themselves, with not much changing in each incarnation. Questions regarding career paths also become exponentially more localized as they become more and more specific, and we can't encourage people to *not* be as specific as possible when asking questions.

Chat, however would be more than suited for this type of discussion. There's also nothing wrong with starting your own (more conventional) forum to handle important topics that just don't fit well inside Q&A.

Comment: I'm sure you're right.  I understand the logistical issues.  But it is frustrating that I want to get a different job, and I know there are thousands of jobs out there, yet there is no cohesive source of information to help me target the correct company.  All the power is in the hands of the employers, who do not know I exist either.  But I understand that SE is not equipped to handle this.  Thanks again, anyway, and I really think SE is incredible nevertheless.

Comment: @David As you appear to be quite eloquent and observant, I **strongly** suggest that you try chat. You're not the _only_ one to realize this :)